How do I reverse a wine install?
I have built wine, the windows emulator from source with a specific patch.
Now accidentally the source directory is removed, after I already run sudo make install.
Is there a way to 'reverse' the install, resulting in an archive or folder?
Could I copy over to other (Linux) machines and end up with the same wine program?
I hope to manage this without having to build wine from source again.

when you built wine the first time, was it with .configure --prefix=/usr … or without --prefix=/usr? Because if the prefix wasn't specified, chances are it just got installed to /usr/local and you can just manually delete everything related to wine from there.

I did not use a specific argument for --prefix. However I do want to save the wine files, and be able to move them, not delete them

yeah, the problem is that you don't know which files these are. So, look whether you have wine-specific things in /usr/local.

There's generally no way to convert a compiled program back to its source tree, no.  If you deleted the source you deleted it.
If the directory got moved by the make install it's more likely somewhere else you can find again, but this would be very unusual.

Well, I do not need the whole source tree back, just in case I would download for example the source tree back, could I get all the builded files/executables back in there moved so it would still be a working wine
